# VLC: how to shuffle playlist? The button is not there

Tags: vlc-media-player

I know there should be a "shuffle" button to randomize playlist items in VLC (and I swear I saw it at some point, but it could've been in my office computer, not sure). It just isn't there.

I have version 2.2.4 and I checked I have the native interface selected, but these are all the buttons I see:

[image: vlc interface]

Where could that option be hiding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way I have found is to put the buttons on my lower controls.

[image: Tools -> Customise Interface]

[image: Drag & Drop Shuffle to Playback Controls]

I realise this is an old post, but the answer was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have access to Windows right now to verify, but on OS X you can click the View tab to enable/disable the shuffle & repeat buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately by default the randomizing doesn't work properly; VLC will randomly play all the tracks in a directory before going to any subdirectories, and then play all those tracks before digging deeper, and so on.

Go to Preferences in VLC and make sure Show settings is set to All, then click Playlist in the left pane. Third from the bottom in the right pane should be a Subdirectory behavior setting, deaulfting to Collapse. Change that to Expand, and voila, VLC's random play function will act more like a true shuffle.

Credit:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_R1NQbnZeQ